# Advanced Wars - Change Main (Assistant) Name

Tags: game-boy-advance, advance-wars

In Advanced Wars there is the main guy (you) not the COs but they refer to you as an assistant. You set this when you first buy the game. I've bought this game used and now everybody is calling me TOM. Can I change this somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do it without restarting your whole game.  However, if you press `L` + `Select` + `Right` directly after turning on your GBA, the delete data option shows up allowing you to delete the data.

[GameFAQs Advance Wars cheats](http://www.gamefaqs.com/gba/471043-advance-wars/cheats)

Comment: This is the only way. I bought my copy used and *hated* the name the previous owner used. I now have a piece of paper taped to the back of the cartridge with this key combination.